# Error in PDFCreator setuplog.txt Port and Print Monitor

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup

I am trying to create a setup for SourceForge PDFCreator using Inno Setup and getting following error in Setuplog.txt:

```
Printerdriver-Directory (Environment: Windows 4.0):
 Result: Success = C:\WINDOWS\System32\spool\DRIVERS\WIN40
Printerdriver-Directory (Environment: Windows NT x86):
 Result: Success = C:\WINDOWS\System32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86
InstallMonitor:
 Monitorname : PDFCreator
 Environment : Windows NT x86
 Result: Error 193 = %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Install printerport:
 Portname : PDF_Creator:
 Result: Success
Install printerdriver for Win2kXP2k3 (32bit):
 Drivername : PDFCreator
 Environment : Windows NT x86
 Result: Success
InstallPrinter:
 Printername: PDFCreator
 Drivername : PDFCreator
 Portname   : PDF_Creator:
 Result: Error 1796 = The specified port is unknown
```

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Look up that error on the [Inno Setup newsgroup search](http://www.jrsoftware.org/newsgroups.php#search), and that should help you I think.